# Where to bind the ViewModel to the View?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, viewmodel

I work on a project(6 pages) target on Windows Phone 7.5 and above. I don't do the pure MVVM model, since handle the navigation event and querystrings is such a pain, and I decide to learn it one by one, and finish the project first :P

Since I am new new to MVVM, I decide not to use MVVM Light, writes all the boilerplate codes myself.
When I finish coding each part, I face a problem.

Where to bind the viewmodel is the most efficient. I read a lot and conclude the points below.

1. create the Model instance in the App.xaml.cs as a property, and make the binding in the codebehind of the view.(This is how the official Data Bound App example does.) But when facing a lots of view (6 pages etc), this may be a problem.

   ```
   public partial class App : Application
   {
       private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;

       /// <summary>
       /// A static ViewModel used by the views to bind against.
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns>The MainViewModel object.</returns>
       public static MainViewModel ViewModel
       {
           get
           {
               // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
               if (viewModel == null)
                   viewModel = new MainViewModel();

               return viewModel;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make a new instance of the viewmodel as a global variable in the code behind of the view. So I can use it through out the view. (as above, I don't do the pure MVVM)
3. In the code behind, in the constructor, do the bindings once.

   ```
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       myViewModel vm = new myViewModel();
       DataContext = vm;
   }
   ```

I read mvvm light which use a ViewModelLocator as a central station. But avoid to use mvvm light, where to bind the viewmodel do you guys think is the best?

Comment: You could also define it in App.xaml or SomePage.xaml as a resource and then bind the DataContext to that resource so you don't even have any code behind. Now you have 5 options. :)  One of the benefits of holding it in App.xaml.cs though is that you can share the same VM instance between different views - if that's what you need at all.

Comment: thanks @igrali now I know when to put the viewmodel in the App section :)

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is just a pattern and it's OK to not use pure mvvm. Personally (and in the end this all comes down to your preference) I think option 3 is ideal.

This is especially true in windows phone due to the view first approach. I also dislike the idea of cluttering my app code with view models. The view code behind I think is a much more natural location to setup and bind the viewmodel. Generally speaking a view model should be for one instance of a view. I wouldn't for example want to have detail pages for different items sharing one detail view model obviously they would show the same data. While a view model can be used by more than one type of view it typically wouldn't be used for multiple instances of views.

The only benefit I can see of putting this in the app code is that you could access your view model instance from anywhere. VM "a" needs to tell vm "b" to refresh. This isn't as common in a mobile platform like this though I've needed this more in drag and drop scenarios or child windows. The good news is if you do need that functionality you still don't need to make static view models you can implement your own or only pull in the messaging library from mvvmlight.

I have 4 apps in the wp marketplace now and I've experimented with view models in the code behind as I suggest for you and MVVM light and caliburn micro. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModelLocator pattern is not restricted to MVVMLight. For this pattern all you need to do is create a class with a set of properties. Each of these properties will return an instance of a view model. In your App.xaml file, within the resource section, you define a resource that will create an instance of this class. Then, in your view, you set the "Source" attribute (of the DataContext) to point to the resource, e.g. Source={StaticResource ....}" and the path will be the name of a property on this StaticResource/Class instance.

In your first example you are close to following this pattern. But, your App class is acting as the ViewModelLocator in that it's exposing an instance of a view model. In the same way that a ViewModelLocator exposes an instance of a view model. The difference being you are binding directly to this App.Property using code-behind instead of using XAML.

The easiest option is 3. Create a new instance and assign it to the data context. But if I were you I would look again at the ViewModelLocator pattern again. It achieves the same thing, but it seperates the management, and lifetime, of your view models away from the views.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to create the ViewModel within `OnNavigatedTo` handler.

I find this is the best place as it's called after the constructor has already been called and it is the first place where navigation parameters are available.

Obviously you have to be careful not to call this when navigating in the back direction (unless your app is recovering from tombstoning) - but that's easy to check for.

This is exactly the lifecycle I use in MvvmCross - the ViewModel is loaded during `OnNavigatedTo` both on WindowsPhone and on WindowsStore.

---

I also agree completely with @Paul's answer that

> Generally speaking a view model should be for one instance of a view

I personally don't like to see ViewModels persisted in singletons, in the app object, etc - I just create a ViewModel each time I create a View.